# Scheduling in Ruby on Rails and stopping sleep method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, delay, sleep

I want to schedule an execution for every 30 mins in Ruby on Rails. I know `sleep` can be used. Is there any other efficient method?

Note that Cron jobs, "whenever" gems won't be helpful since I dont want it as a job just a part of execution. And once `sleep` is called, is there any other way to wake it up other than aborting it?

Comment: sleep is not efficient.I did it using delayed_jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might "wake it" by catching process signals

```
trap('INT') do
  # do something
end
```

To wake up a thread, you call the 'run' method, even if it is in the 'sleep' status, it will resume execution

```
t = Thread.new do
  puts 'going to sleep'
  sleep 100
  loop do
    puts '.'
  end
end

loop do
  sleep 3
  puts t.status
  t.run
end
```

You could do the same with main thread, just be sure to fetch it with Thread::main

```
Thread.new do
  sleep 3
  puts Thread::main.status
  Thread::main.run
end

puts 'going to sleep'
sleep 100
loop do
  puts '.'
end
```